# Version control to manage club project?

Tags: java, version-control, robocode

At my school, we're starting a coding competition for our CS club to help out our freshmen learn the practices of fast turn around times, due dates, code comparison, and API documentation using [Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/).  I was wondering if there was a way to allow each member to work on their own packages/robots and pull them into a central location for comparison and competition?  I'd like to be able to pull all of the projects onto my laptop but allow club members to keep their packages separate and only work on their parts of it.  A cross platform solution is ideal.

Answer (score 5):

You could post your code on Github or Google Code for free and use that if you don't mind everyone being able to look at it. You could all have your own separate repositories out there and just view them there.

Otherwise, I would go with Subversion on a central server. There are plenty of free options out there like Unfuddle and Springloops that offer free plans. You could create a folder for each of you or create separate repositories. The downside on those free packages is the number of users.

Of course, the most customizable way would be to use your own server. The only problem with that is the complexity of configuring all of it. Subversion and Git are both pretty easy to set up though.

Answer (score 2):

Git has a really nice feature called [submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

It lets you group any number of unique git repositories into another repository. This way, all the programmers create their own repos, and then you can create a super project to link them all together.

There is a good description on how to do this at the [Pro Git online book](http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html).